# Selecionar registro ente o primeiro dia do mês X e o ultimo dia do mês X

Tags: mysql

Como seria a Query do MySQL para eu pegar todos os registros do mês selecionado (usando um select)?

Campo data é do tipo Date.

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE primeiro-dia-do-mes-x BETWEEN ultimo-dia-do-mes-x ORDER BY data ASC
```

Eu seleciono o mês e ano em um campo Select do Html, então nessa data vou entrar com mês e ano sendo variável.

Obrigado.

Comment: e não leva em consideração o ano? vai pegar datas de um mesmo mês em anos diferentes, ou só tem **sempre** 1 ano na tabela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brenno, segue uma sugestão utilizando as função STR_TO_DATE para fazer a conversão dos parâmetros mes e ano de string para data, e a função LAST_DAY para obter o último dia do mes:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE 
    data BETWEEN 
        STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01/', @mes, '/', @ano), '%d/%m/%Y' ) AND
        LAST_DAY( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01/', @mes, '/', @ano), '%d/%m/%Y' ) )
ORDER BY data ASC
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem uma data pode usar a função [Month](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) e [Year](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)
do MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE MONTH(campodata) BETWEEN MesInicial AND MesFinal
```